# Is the anime "BTOOOM!" an adaptation of a movie called "The Condemned"?

Tags: btooom

The first thing in both *BTOOOM!* and [*The Condemned*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Condemned) is based on the same story, which is surviving in the middle-of-nowhere island.

Is the anime an adaptation of the movie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both "BTOOOM!" and "The Condemned" are actually using conception of "Battle Royale" novel by Koushun Takami, that's the only reason they share same theme (participants of survival game have to kill each other, so last survivor can leave island).

Comment: Here it is, I've been knowed the answer after I create this question, so... it's okay to answer it, thanks before.